# Empty observable after another button is clicked in angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular6

So I am using an Observable in angular6 to search my database as the user types and bring back results. So I am using the async pipe along with the Observable.

To render the results, in my html I have

```
<div *ngIf='results | async; let items'>
  <div *ngFor='let item of items'><button type="button" (click)="getByName(item.id,cepDropValue)" name="button">{{item.name}}</button></div
</div>
```

The `results` is the `Observable<SearchResult[]>` observable and it is defined as  `this.results = this.nameForm.valueChanges.pipe(...`.

What I want to do is to hide the `<div *ngIf='results | async; let items'>...` as soon a result button is clicked. So everytime a button is clicked, what do I have to do in the `getByName` function?

I imported empty from the `rxjs` and tried something like

```
  getByName(id,cep){
     this.results = EMPTY; //also tried '' and false
    this.mapcmsService.getById(id,cep).subscribe((data) =>{
       //grab the data 
    })
}
```

This is not working. Somehow I have to empty out the `results`, so I can hide the 
 `div`. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Since an Observable is a stream it seems conceptually odd to "empty" it. It may be more appropriate to `complete` it and start a new stream?

Comment: @DeborahK "Empty it" is just a figure of speech. I dont knw what to actually do, I just need something that hides the `div`. I will try `complete` and let you know

Comment: I didn't follow exactly what you are trying to do ... but couldn't you just use a simple Boolean flag to turn on/off the div and set it on/off in the desired places of the code?

Comment: First, you don't need the first `<div>` you can directly do `*ngFor='let items of results | async'`

Comment: @DeborahK Somehow hide the `<div *ngIf='results | async; let items'>` when the `<button type="button" (click)="getByName(item.id,cepDropValue)" name="button">{{item.name}}</button>` button is clicked

Comment: @Florian I get `Can't have multiple template bindings on one element.` error

Comment: I'm writing an answer, suggesting a different approach, but an easy one.

Answer (score 1):

For your need, I will suggest another approach, however it might not be the best.
I would subscribe to your observable inside the component typescript file instead of using  `| async` in the template.

*(Please, replace the any type below by your specific type)*
**your-class.component.ts**

```
private results$: Observable<any>;
private isAlive = true;
private items= any[];

public ngOninit(){
  this.results$
    .takeWhile(() => this.isAlive)
    .subscribe((res) => {
      this.items = res;
    });
}

public ngOnDestroy(){
  this.isAlive = false;
}

private removeFromArray(element) {
  const index = this.items.indexOf(element);
  if (index > -1) {
    this.items.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

private getByName(item, cepDropValue) {
  // if this is an http request, then you can keep the subscription like that.
  // Otherwise, use the takeWhile() to unsubscribe automatically on
  // component destruction
  this.removeFromArray(item); // delete
  this.mapcmService.getById(item.id, cepDropValue)
    .subscribe(() => 
      // grab data
    );
}
```

**your-class.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor='let item of items'>
  <button type="button"
          (click)="getByName(item, cepDropValue)"
          name="button" />
  <span>{{item.name}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Florian, thank you for the effort, but I am ashamed to say that there is a simpler approach that works. I should think of this, before even ask here. Are you ready? When the button is clicked, I reset the form, so it gets empty, it searches for nothing and so, the `results` is empty and there is nothing showing. You see that? See how stupid I am? Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: The new problem is that my html is actually like `<div *ngIf='results | async; let items'>
  <div *ngFor='let item of items'><button type="button" (click)="getByName(item.id,cepDropValue)" name="button">{{item.name}}</button></div>
  <div *ngIf='items.length == 0'>No Results</div>
</div>` so I see "No Results" even when I just click a button, but I should not see that , because I just clicked something, its not that there are no search results. I tried `<div *ngIf='!nameForm.touched && items.length == 0'>No Results</div>` to only make it appear after a failed search, but it does not work

Comment: If you have a plunkr or any external link that will help me to understand what you're trying to do it, and how it can be improve. You say you're resetting your **form** but I didn't even know your html is in a `form` element ?